# JQuery Mobile - Dynamically Updating Images in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a jquery mobile formatted version of a site (running off ColdFusion 10). As part of this I am trying to dynamically update an icon that expands and collapses a div as required. I am just using the following to dynamically update the icons class and title attributes depending on its current state. This works perfectly on Chrome but doesn't seem to work consistently on IE8 or 9. Just wondering if anyone might have experienced this problem before?

```
<cfset buttonCSS = "ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">
<cfset showButtonCSS = buttonCSS & " ui-icon-carat-d greenGlow">
<cfset hideButtonCSS = buttonCSS & " ui-icon-carat-u redGlow">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

<cfoutput>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on("click", "#idName", function(e){  
          $(".myDiv").toggle("slow");

          if($("#idName").attr("class") == "<cfoutput>#showButtonCSS#</cfoutput>"){
            $("#idName").attr("class", "<cfoutput>#hideButtonCSS#</cfoutput>");
            $("#idName").attr("title", "Hide");
          }
          else{
            $("#idName").attr("class", "<cfoutput>#showButtonCSS#</cfoutput>");
            $("#idName").attr("title", "Show all");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </cfoutput>

<cfoutput>
  <a href="##" id="idName" class="#showButtonCSS#" title="Show all">Show/Hide</a>
</cfoutput>
```

To test what is happening I have added alert($("#idName").attr("class")); before and after the IF statement and it does show the correct values but they are not reflected on screen.

Is this a bug or is there a better way I could achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, how about using .hasClass, .addClass, .removeClass functions instead of using cfoutput all class string?

Comment: Hi Sho, I tried the following but still got the same result:    if($("#idName").hasClass("ui-icon-carat-d")){ $("#idName").removeClass("ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-d"); $("#idName").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-u"); } else{ $("#idName").removeClass("ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-u"); $("#idName").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-d"); }

Comment: Sorry, just realised the above should have been simplified to (still doesn't work, however): if($("#idName").hasClass("ui-icon-carat-d")){
    $("#idName").removeClass("ui-icon-carat-d");
    $("#idName").addClass("ui-icon-carat-u");
  }
  else{
    $("#idName").removeClass("ui-icon-carat-u");
    $("#idName").addClass("ui-icon-carat-d");
  }

Comment: Not related to the issue, you can chain the functions, like .removeClass("ui-icon-carat-u").addClass("ui-icon-carat-d"). :)

Comment: what happens in IE8 and IE9? Basically IE9 should work like Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing some classic conditionals for specific IE you are supporting.

CSS

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
- http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

jQuery

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
   //IE
} else {
   //NOT IE
}
```

Or classic IE specific JS.

```
/*@cc_on
document.write("JScript version: " + @_jscript_version + ".<br>");
   /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
      document.write("JScript Version 5.0 or better.<br \/>");
      document.write("This text is only seen by browsers that support JScript 5+<br>");
   @else @*/
      document.write("This text is seen by all other browsers (ie: Firefox, IE 4.x etc)<br>");
   /*@end
@*/
```

Comment: Hi Secret Agent, unfortunately I can't figure out how to get this working properly in IE as yet.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found that doing something like the following seems to work on Chrome as well as IE8 and IE9:

```
if($("#idName").hasClass("ui-icon-carat-d")){   
  $("#testSpan").html("<a href='##' id='idName' class='<cfoutput>#hideButtonCSS#</cfoutput>' title='Hide'>Show/Hide</a>");
}
else{
  $("#testSpan").html("<a href='##' id='idName' class='<cfoutput>#showButtonCSS#</cfoutput>' title='Show all'>Show/Hide</a>");
}

<span id="testSpan"><a href='##' id='idName' class='#showButtonCSS#' title='Show all'>Show/Hide</a></span>
```

As you can see it's not very elegant but it seems to do the job. I'm still puzzled as to why the approach in the OP doesn't work properly across all browsers, however.

Comment: OK, now this isn't working in IE8 anymore. Frustrating.